# ThreeJS Object camera perspective seems to be distorting model

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, perspectivecamera

Why don't the lines of the first extremity stay exaclty over the lines on the second extremity since the radius is the same on both? And how can I achieve that?

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 600 / 500, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 700);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match it exactly, take a look  at the `orthographicCamera` http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/OrthographicCamera. Here is an example where you can switch between the two camera types: https://va3c.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic2.html

Hence the name it doesnt have the distortion the perspective camera has, so if your two objects are the same size in code they will be displayed the same size.

If you dont want to use an orthographic camera try setting the `fov` to a low value like `20` and move a little bit back to reduce the distortion.